Can I have a single markdownlint options.config for all markdown files?
I have a .markdownlint.yaml file that makes markdownlint behave as I want it to. I don't really need to customize this by project, and would much rather have it set somewhere once and for all. Is there any place where I can put my file and forget about it? In case this is relevant, I use markdownlint from within neovim.

which implementation of markdownlint? there seem to be several

for example, this one uses $HOME/.mdlrc

Thanks, I've linked to the relevant (DavidAnson's) implementation. Unfortunately it's not the one you linked to. I'm trying not to deviate too much from LazyVim's standard choices.

https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/issues/1029 ?

https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/issues/825

https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint/issues/466

Thanks! Looks like I have the same problem as some of these folks, and am looking at the wrong project.
